# What are benefits of renderToNodeStream vs renderToString?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I cannot find any information about the benefits of renderToNodeStream.
Also, I checked next.js and they still using renderToString.

Do you know any real benefit for the business of using this new way of rendering?
Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`renderToNodeStream` creates a pipe or stream and it sends little pieces of data from this stream to the browser. the data is the whole project that is rendered into the formats the browser understands. one of it's priorities to `renderToString` is that making that stream and connecting to the browser and more importantly sending smaller data make it faster for the browser to get the first byte .TTFB which is short for Time To First Byte can be imporoved by using `renderToNodeStream`.it also improves server initial response time which plays an important role in the score of performance of your site.